# How can i make button visible after i made it invisble?

Tags: java, button, onclicklistener, visible, invisible

I made a button Invisible in Java using On Click Listener.
Now I want to make the button visible again how can I do it?

Comment: Assuming this is a jButton and you used `myButton.setVisibility(false);`, can you just `myButton.setVisibility(true);`?

Comment: Setting a button to be invisible also effectively makes it unclickable. That means that you will not be able to set it to be visible again in its own OnClick; you'll have to put the `setVisibility` call elsewhere, perhaps on a different button.

Answer (score -1):

Using swt as an example, ensure you declare the widget somewhere that is accessible by all the areas you want to change visibility.

```
Button myButton;  // eg. instance variable
```

Then create the button (eg. in your Composite..)

```
myButton = new Button(..);
```

Then each place (eg. in your listeners) you can set these to either true or false:

```
myButton.setVisible(true);
myButton.setVisible(false);
```